# Category has_many videos, video belongs_to_many categories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations

I'm doing like a little video site like 9gagtv style 
and videos in the site has a category so the user can find all the Tech videos for example 
but some videos belongs_to_many categories like when a video is about tech but also is funny so it will show up in both categories videos and i'm not sure how to do this?
would it require more than one t.references in videos table ? how would the relationship go?

category.rb

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
has_many :videos
end
```

video.rb

```
class Video < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :category
end
```

category migrations

```
class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
def change
create_table :categories do |t|
    t.string :title
  t.timestamps
end
end
end
```

video migrations

```
class CreateVideos < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
def change
create_table :videos do |t|
    t.string :url
    t.string :title
    t.text :description
    t.integer :duration
    t.references :category, foreign_key: true
  t.timestamps
  end
 end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [has_and_belongs_to_many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)
to create many-to-many association through the third table.

Models:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :videos
end

class Video < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

Migrations:

```
class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :categories do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateVideos < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :videos do |t|
      t.string :url
      t.string :title
      t.text :description
      t.integer :duration
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateCategoriesVideos < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :categories_videos do |t|
      t.references :category, index: true
      t.references :video, index: true
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is **has_and_belongs_to_many** relation ([see more](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many))

It should look something like that

Category

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many:videos
end
```

Video

```
class Video < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
end
```

And migration

```
class CreateCategoriesVideosJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :categories_videos, id: false do |t|
      t.integer :category_id
      t.integer :video_id
    end
  end
end
```